# Tkinter error (_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "Serif")

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

I have recently started using tkinter, and I am creating a program that displays all the fonts styles in the program my code is:

```
label7=Label(second_frame,text="This is font: Courier",font=font.families()[7]).grid(row=7,column=0)
label8=Label(second_frame,text="This is font: MS Serif",font=font.families()[8]).grid(row=8,column=0)
label9=Label(second_frame,text="This is font: MS Sans Serif",font=font.families()[9]).grid(row=9,column=0)
label10=Label(second_frame,text="This is font: Small Fonts",font=font.families()[10]).grid(row=10,column=0)
label11=Label(second_frame,text="This is font: Adobe Caslon Pro Bold",font=font.families()[11]).grid(row=11,column=0)
label12=Label(second_frame,text="This is font: Adobe Caslon Pro",font=font.families()[12]).grid(row=12,column=0)
```

I have read some other articles where they suggest to use tuples, but I too have used the tuples still the problem persists. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well a the entire error output.

Comment: Changing `font=font.families()[7]` to `font=(font.families()[7],)` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this:
`label9 = Label(second_frame, text="This is font: MS Sans Serif",  font=(font.families()[9],12)).grid(row=9,column=0)`

The change is in giving **font** a tuple with font size.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has answered me and this works exactly fine.
You need to changethe code to:
font=(font.families()[7],)
Thank you @acw1668 (I don't know whether using @ works here or not but just trying)
Thank you everyone
Have a good day ahead, or night maybe, WHATEVER